# app crash when button is clicked

Tags: android-activity

this is the class from where I want to call other class using button. The `bTicketRes` button and `bAddBusData` works fine but the 3rd button i.e `bEditSms` when clicked, the app cashes.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(view.getId())
    {
    case R.id.bTicketRes:
        TicketReservationView.setDatabase(database);    
        Intent it = new Intent(MainView.this,TicketReservationView.class);
        startActivity(it);
        break;
    case R.id.bAddBusData:
        BusDataManager.setDatabase(database);
        Intent ib = new Intent(MainView.this, BusDataManager.class);
        startActivity(ib);
        break;

    case R.id.bEditSms:
        CustomSms.setDatabase(database);
        Intent is = new Intent(MainView.this,CustomSms.class);
        startActivity(is);
        break;
```

and this is the class which i want to call using button in above class

```
public class CustomSms extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
private static Database database;
private Button bSaveSms,bBack1;
private EditText customSms,timeDelay;
private SQLiteDatabase db;
public String savSms, timeDly;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.edit_sms);

    customSms = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etcustomSms);
    timeDelay = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ettimeDelay);

    bSaveSms   = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bSaveSms);
    bBack1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bBack1);

    bSaveSms.setOnClickListener(this);
    bBack1.setOnClickListener(this);

}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(v.getId())
    {
    case R.id.bSaveSms:
        db = database.getWritableDatabase();
        database.deleteOld(db, savSms, timeDly);
        savSms = customSms.getText().toString();
        timeDly= timeDelay.getText().toString();
        database.insert_message_data(savSms, timeDly, db);
        showToast("Message Saved Successfully");
        //Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Data Saved Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        db.close();
        break;
    case R.id.bBack1:
        customSms.setText("");
        timeDelay.setText("");
        Intent is = new Intent(CustomSms.this, MainView.class);
        startActivity(is);
        break;
    }


}
public static void setDatabase(Database dbase) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    database = dbase;
}

public void showToast(final String title)
{
    final View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.toast_layout, null);
       AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
       TextView tv = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.toastTitle);
       final AlertDialog ad = alertDialogBuilder.create();
       ad.setTitle("Notification");

       ad.setView(view);
       tv.setText(title);

       ad.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ad.dismiss();
        }
    });
       ad.show();

}
```

when I click button in above class to call the below class, suddenly app crashes and the above class is restarted. I want that below class should be called upon pressing button in above class

Comment: Could you include stacktrace from logcat?

Comment: well that problem is solved but now another problm is created,when the app receives sms, the activity crashes and app restarts